# custom css coding not working to remove login button, after login in top nav menu in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm simply trying to hide the login button after user has logged into the site. I've tried writing the custom css in various ways, including the main two below. Action still not working. Please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
.logged-in .main-header-menu .login-link{
    display: none;
}

.logged-in .main-header-menu .menu-link, .ast-header-custom-item a{
    color:  var( --e-global-color-primary );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code in your functions.php

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', function () {

  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  ?>
    <style>
       /** please use the exact call of login button, you can verify class by changing button color **/
       .logged-in .main-header-menu .login-link{
          display: none;
       }
    </style>
  <?php
  }

});

?>
```

Comment: Hi Ali! I see that you are new to, so welcome to the platform! Thank you for responding, and for doing so, so quickly too! I am not a coder in any sense, just started doing some learning and research today, and so I have some clarifying questions, like a 2 year old. When you say "use the exact call of the login button" What does that mean? The button is called "login" if that helps and it's on my main top nav menu bar, if that helps.  The second set of code that I posted is exactly the code for the menu header that was placed by wordpress, not me, just FYI. Continuing in new comment...

Comment: I was instructed to place my simple code/command of ".logged-in" in front of the code that I wanted it to reflect upon, i.e. header menu, which is why I included it in my example/question. In WP, the code ".logged-in" is auto integrated to command the removal of what ever value you place it in front of it upon logging into the site. So... Im trying to figure out exactly which pieces of the code that you posted that I need to copy/paste and what values i need to replace with the "login" demand. I hope that this clarity helps to answer my question vs. add further confusion.